# Asynchronous treatment sometimes causes MS Access query to crash

Tags: vb.net, winforms, ms-access, datagridview

I am working on a Winform program that uses Access (unfortunately, my firm isn't willing to go for a non-shared-drive-only server at this point) and VB.NET. I have a report that takes and displays data from the database for particular deals that works 95% of the time. 5% of the time, though, it crashes. I know that it has nothing to do with the code itself, because when it crashes is totally irrespective of which deal is being displayed. I can also consistently crash the program by clicking the triggering "View Deal" button repeatedly (this is after experimenting with sleeping the thread and disabling the button while the code executes).

The typical error when the program crashes relates to the processing of the data I'm doing before displaying it. For instance, I add a total row to the data table for some of the cash flows and then sum it up in VB. I then bind this to a DataGridView. During a crash, though, the error message says that the first column I reference doesn't exist.

Does anyone have any thoughts on how to get VB.NET to treat this synchronously? I know that Access is slow to begin with, but it's even worse when it's being used over a network (as in my case), so I want to be able to prevent this sort of thing from happening to my users.

Thanks

Rob

Comment: Then the first column doesn't exist.. there is like a concurrency issue (which can exist without explicit thread usage, and may or may not relate to cross-threading)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Any thoughts on how to deal with it?

Comment: Analyze the program and fix the problem. Since no code is posted here, there really isn't much more to say than such generalities. However, trust the error messages.

Comment: Actually, if by concurrency you mean another user is updating the database, that's not the case--at the moment I'm really the only user.

Comment: Is it possible to disable all multithreading, explicit or not?

Answer (score 0):

I think it was concurrency, so thanks to user2864740. It was concurrency in a roundabout way, though. I had several sub calls to a sub that would run a query and then add a row to a DataGridView. It turns out that I wasn't closing the connection in the sub each time, so when I tried to "bust" the program by repeatedly running the code, Access became overloaded with connections. Eventually, the code tried to move beyond the queries, since they wouldn't run anyway, and that's why I was getting issues with the DataGridView.

Hope this helps someone in the future.